# Increasing output current from ZVS driver

Tags: current, transformer, output, flyback, zvs

I bought the ZVS driver as shown in the picture below:
[image]

After connecting a flyback transformer, I tried measuring the voltage and current at the output. The open circuit voltage is about 12KV. To measure the current I used around 560Ohm resistor at the output in series and used ammeter to measure. But the ammeter showed a very low current of about 40mA only. Any idea or suggestions to increase the current to 200mA. I tried to play around by increasing the number pf primary turns of flyback transformer but I couldn't increase beyond about 15-16 turns and I didn't see much increase in output current. I am using adapter of 12V 2A rating as input to driver.

How can I increase the output current from the flyback?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the EE.SE. Note that if you need \$200\mathrm{mA}\$ at \$12\mathrm{kV}\$, you are talking \$200\mathrm{mA}\cdot 12\mathrm{kV}=2400\mathrm{W}\$: simply stated, this means that you need a completely new ZVS circuit since I doubt that the one shown in the picture you provide is capable to manage such power levels.

Comment: Not exactly 200mA at 12KV, but 2-3KV at 130mA with load of 560Ohm would suffice my requirements. Thanks a lot

Comment: \$2\mathrm{kV} \cdot 130\mathrm{mA}=260\mathrm{W}\$ is quite high, do you have the ZVS Driver exactly as in the picture?  Please also provide the link of it.